# in Rails how do I grab an element with a dynamically created id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I have an index page with multiple divs of listings.  each div has a dynamically created id, in this case edit_<%= address.id%>.  I'm trying to write some jquery so that as I hover over an individual div, some hidden links are shown, or as I click on the edit link for this individual listing, a form pops up.  I'm able to do it inline like this:

```
onclick="$('#edit_<%= address.id %>').dialog();"
```

but once in my application.js file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#edit_<%= @address.id%>').dialog();
});
```

It doesn't work.  now I'm assuming it's because I'm using it outside of the view/controller where this variable actually has meaning.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: `application.js` is an app-wide file, and not an erb template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a specific class name for all of the target DIVs. Even though they will have a dynamic ID if you use a pre-defined class name you will be able to locate them using a simple jQuery. You can then write code in your application JS files and target only those specific class names.

Update: Here is an example that gives you what you want. This is straight HTML/Javascript but the container DIVs use a unique ID but common class name. You can easily move this into your Rails app:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .hidden-div {
        border: 1px solid silver;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .hidden-div DIV {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(function() { 
        $(".hidden-div").hover(function() {
          // we are hovering over a hidden-div class
          $(this).children("div").show();
        }, function() {
          // we are moving out of a hidden-div class
          $(this).children("div").hide();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="random-id-1434" class="hidden-div">
      Hover over me to reveal my hidden fields
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
    </div>

    <div id="random-id-342" class="hidden-div">
      Hover over me to reveal my hidden fields
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
    </div>

    <div id="random-id-887" class="hidden-div">
      Hover over me to reveal my hidden fields
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
      <div>A hidden field</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: right, but I want to single out each specific div I hover over.  I've done it this way and when I hover over the first div, all of the hidden links pop up in each div. I only want them to show up for the one I'm over at the moment.

Comment: I've added an example that illustrates what you need. Let me know if you have any further questions. If this works for you please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work.....maybe i'm not explaining it right.  So i have a list of things, using form_for, each has a dynamically created id.  since new items can be created at any time and each new item will have a new random-ish id, I need to have a way to select the item by whatever this id is.  seemingly I would be able to use something like: $('#edit_<%= address.id %>') but obviously javascript doesn't know what my ruby code means

Comment: How are you creating the new items? Are you using javascript or JS partials? If you can provide a sample of the code that might help me understand where you're going wrong.

Comment: '<% @addresses.each do |address| %>
    <div class='listing-container'>
      <div class="address-container grid_10" id="address-container-<%= address.id %>" >' so I misspoke  before....my list of addresses is being created by an each do statement. if you look at the id's : address-container-<%= address.id%> you can see that they will all be created based on what the individual address id is.  I want to hover over one of the div's displaying an address, and have the hidden links display only for this address div.  so I have to find a way to pass that id to jquery.

Comment: I'm thinking I have to use (this) somehow.  I tried selecting the class $('.address-container.grid_10').mouseenter(function() { $(this).siblings().css('visibility','show'); to no avail because I am selecting all of the div's with the same class, not just the one I'm hovering over

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a rails variable in your JavaScript file, and that is not how it works. I think the easiest solution for you is simply to use the [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem.

Comment: Gon hasn't worked so far because I can't pass dynamic id's in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your css elements have the same starting id or class and then you can select them using some jquery similar to this, which selects all divs with edit at the beginning of their id `$('div[id^="#edit_"]').hover.dialog();`

below is some documentation on how to use this selector

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: right, but then if I hover over one of the divs won't the links pop up on all of the divs? I only want the hidden links to pop up as I hover over each individual link

Comment: try adding in a .hover if you want it to appear on hover. http://api.jquery.com/hover/   also add some more code, its not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.